# How do I tell GCC and Clang to look at /usr/local/cuda for include/libs?

Tags: shell, gcc

I have installed CUDA on my system, but seems like its files are not being found by libraries that depend on it. What should I append to my `.bashrc` in order for both GCC and Clang to look on the directories `/usr/local/cuda/include` and `/usr/local/cuda/lib` ?

Answer (score 6):

Both the GCC and Clang drivers respect the following environment variables:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib
```

Check the manuals.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it:

```
gcc -I/path_of_include_files -L/path_of_load_libraries_files
```

NOTE: you can have some `-I` and some `-L`  such as :

```
gcc -I. -L. -I../include -L../libs
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `gcc` and `clang` respect some environment variables that can help achieve what you want. Try adding these to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export CFLAGS="-I /usr/local/cuda/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L /usr/local/cuda/lib"
```

However this is usually not done on a global level - different projects need different includes and libs so best to configure the custom include and lib directories per-project in your `Makefile` or using `./configure`.

Comment: This answer is misleading. `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` aren't environment variables related to GCC or Clang. These are make variables merely respected by convention.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working `pkgconfig`, then you can use it to add appropriate GCC flags:

```bash
$(pkg-config --cflags cuda) $(pkg-config --libs cuda)
```

For example:

```bash
gcc filename.c -o outputfile $(pkg-config --cflags --libs cuda)
```

In a Makefile, that would normally look like:

```
CFLAGS += $(pkg-config --cflags cuda)
LIBS += $(pkg-config --libs cuda)
```

Comment: for this you will need the pkg-config utility installed, which is present in most of unix like oses